# Matching classes that are calling to methods

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

Just for fun, I keep trying to come up with a regex, that will match any of my (example) following calls:

```
Respone::json(...)
Redirect::to(...)
View::make(...)
```

I'm trying to match the characters and the two `:` (ex: `Response::`, or any of the following), before the method with the following regex: `(^[\w][:]{2}$)` in Sublime Text 2. But I can't figure it out, why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(^[\w][:]{2}$)
            ^
```

The `$` character means end of line. Your regex will match only if the `:` character (last character in the regex) is at the end of the line.

Just remove it:

```
(^[\w][:]{2})
```

Also, you don't need a character llass for `\w` or `:` alone, and you need to us a quantifier:

```
(^\w+:{2})
```

Should work.

Might also be safer to use negated class: `[^:]`:

```
(^[^:]+:{2})
```

Comment: With all do respect, but none of the versions mentioned actually work

Comment: @w0rldart Did you make sure you're using the regular expression find?

Comment: @w0rldart I don't know why it doesn't match. Here are some screenshots: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8mn3h.png and http://i.stack.imgur.com/9fmCS.png. I have v2.0.2.

Comment: really weird, this thing

Comment: @w0rldart Could you provide a screenshot of what you have and what is matching which shouldn't match? Maybe there's a wrong assumption I made?